# What does counter-point mean when playing guitar?

Tags: guitar, terminology

My band has been fooling around with the tape machine and the bass player suggested that I play counter-point to the track I already did. What does he mean?

Comment: Probably worth asking him. Either he'll know and explain it properly, or won't, and will look a bit of a ****.

Comment: @Tim-I guess I don't wish to reveal my own ****ishness to him. There's politics everywhere.

Comment: Counterpoint means the same in music whether it's guitar, piano, trumpet or flute. Google it too, and note the many choices for definitions. Then ask him.

Comment: @Tim-As usual, your comments are pretty much spot on and helpful to me. Why can't I think that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were playing a melody, play a different one that weaves against it, rather than just doubling up or adding a harmony line.   More generally, he's probably suggesting you 'fill in the gaps' of what you played before.  Have a musical conversation with it!